# Importing 'react-native-vector-icon' results 'Unable to resolve module '@expo/vector-icons' error

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons` from `E:\React Projects\Tourism\src\screens\TouristInformation\TouristInformation.js`: Module `@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (E:\React Projects\Tourism\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (E:\React Projects\Tourism\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:49:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (E:\React Projects\Tourism\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:218:16)
    at Object.resolve (E:\React Projects\Tourism\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:141:30)
    at dependencies.map.result (E:\React Projects\Tourism\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:373:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (E:\React Projects\Tourism\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:369:18)
    at E:\React Projects\Tourism\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:188:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (E:\React Projects\Tourism\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:298:30)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░ 48.8% (311/450), failed.

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2019:21:01:47 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.11.0"
```

I ejected the project running 'expo eject'.
Then I added 'react-native-vector-icon' to use font icons provided by that package. But, whenever I import that library to any of my js file. Though I'm importing 'react-native-vector-icon',it shows the above error.

**TouristInformation.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import residentBackgroundImage from '../../assets/residentBackground.jpg';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
export default class TouristInformation extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Image
          source = {residentBackgroundImage}
          style = {styles.image} />
        <Text> Yomuna </Text>
      <Icon name="ios-person" size={30} color="#4F8EF7" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image:{

  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have @expo/vector-icons installed as a dependency?  If so, it may be conflicting with react-native-vector-icons (react-native-vector-icons is already a dependency of @expo/vector-icons).Since you've already ejected from Expo I'm not sure you want that package installed.

react-native-vector-icons requires you to link native dependencies.  The first thing to try is `react native link` from the terminal. It seems to work better with iOS than with Android. If that doesn't work there are other manual ways to do it.

[From the RN docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios)
[From the package docs (scroll down to the Android section)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @stever. I ran 'react-native link' and even tried manually linking the project. But the error seems to persist. I tried resolving it following those suggestion listed on error screen (resetting metro bundler, removing haste cache, deleting node_module folder)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with `babel-preset-expo'.

To resolve, do the following:

- Run `yarn remove babel-preset-expo`
- Run`yarn add metro-react-native-babel-preset`
- In your `babel.config.js`, remove `babel-preset-expo` from presets, and instead add `module:metro-react-native-babel-preset`

Your `babel.config.js` should now look something like this:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands.

```
npm i react-native-vector-icons
npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```