# React-native expo vector icons not showing on android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, native, expo

In my code I have the following import statement:

import { FontAwesome, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

and I am using it like this:

< Ionicons name='md-checkmark-circle' size={50} />

When running on my android device connected via usb, I only see a box with an X inside. Not the expected icon. I have searched and cannot find a similar problem, except those using the react-native-vector-icon library.

Comment: If you are willing to eject from Expo, you can try this very popular library.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons.  If you do, make sure you follow the linking directions.  I answered a similar question (from someone who ejected) about 20 minutes ago.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244436/importing-react-native-vector-icon-results-unable-to-resolve-module-expo-ve/54244587#54244587

Comment: I'm trying really hard not to eject. And it shouldn't be necessary considering @expo/vector-icons is just the compatibility layer around react-native-vector-icons.  But I'll keep that in mind if it comes to it. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing Christopher.

Comment: Are you using FontAwesome in this component as well?  If not, try not importing it...

Comment: Yep, tested FontAwesome to see if it was an issue with Ionicons but both icons are the boxes

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Matias I actually just copied my code elsewhere, deleted the project, set up a new project, copied the old files into the new project and then it worked. So unfortunately I don't know what went wrong with the first project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ChristopherHurt, I've got it working as well,  I just don't remember how I did it. I didn't have to set up a new project though.